# python GTK menuitem label that is the return of another function

Tags: python, gtk, menuitem, indicator

I'm working on a simple indicator in Ubuntu with python and I want the menuitem to display the return of a function and refresh every "n" second.

Here is what I have:

```
def build_menu():
    menu = gtk.Menu()
    item_internetstatus = gtk.MenuItem("Internet : " + internetstatus())
    menu.append(item_internetstatus)
```

The function is `internetstatus()` and my objective is to run `internetstatus()` every n seconds so that the menuitem label is also updated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can repeatedly call `gtk.MenuItem.set_label()` with `glib.timeout_add()`.

Comment: could you please direct me to a documentation about gtk.MenuItem.set_label() and glib.timeout_add() because, I'm not having any luck with them.

Comment: Here is the doc for [gtk.MenuItem.set_label](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkmenuitem.html#method-gtkmenuitem--set-label) and for [glib.timeout_add](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add).

Comment: thank you for your efforts.

Comment: its not working or I can't find the correct way to do this. any more help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example (a stripped down version of the code you have so far)?